# Regular expression to replace all &apos; between two tags

Tags: php, regex, tags, replace

How do I replace all `&apos;` with `'` between `<?php` and `?>` tags with regular expression in PHP?

My string: `<?php $test = &apos;hello&apos;; ?>`

Comment: how did that happen? And why do you have to do the replacement with PHP and cannot do it directly in your IDE?

Comment: Where is that string coming from?

Answer (score 1):

```
use str_replace

$test =" &apos;hello&apos;;"

str_replace("&apos","'",$test )
```